# How to Connect Android Emulator to Host Network?

Tags: networking, android, google-chrome-os

**Let me know if this is better off on a different site.**

So, I've been asking around, and have yet to get an answer as to how to connect hardware devices to a Google Chromebook that runs Android apps. I want to connect hardware and have Android apps act as drivers.

The issue is that Android apps on Chromebooks are still basically emulated, and too containerized to the point where the host OS (Chrome) recognizes that USB/LAN devices are connected, but the Android layer does not.

Before I return this $500 Samsung Chromebook Pro and opt for an actual Android device, I'd like to know if there is a workaround for this.

What I am specifically trying to do is use the Chromebook as a touch-based point-of-sale using Square. I tried using a USB receipt printer, and Square didn't recognize it in-app. I've since returned that, thinking that maybe it was a fluke and that I should just use a LAN printer anyways. I now have a Square compatible Star TSP100 LAN receipt printer, and Square still cannot find the printer in-app.

With that said, [here are the networks my Chromebook list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/458F9.png) There are multiple networks listed, but the ones with "arc" and "android" in the name refer to the emulated Android on the Chromebook.

Because every Android app I run is on a different LAN network than my receipt printer, it's impossible for any of those apps to detect it. The only printers that are detected are Google Cloud printers, or printers added strictly from print plugins/services. Square does everything in-app, so the printer has to be on the same network the app is communicating over.

From what I understand, the Android container has a different network as a security measure. But isn't there any sort of way to conduct all traffic through the host? I can obviously sign in to accounts, download apps and games, and much more using Android apps on here. It's just the matter that there's an entirely separate LAN and I'm wondering if there's a way to eliminate that.

I'm willing to try anything at this point.